# Ubuntu is lagging after deleting gvfs and gvfs-admin

Tags: gvfs, administrator

Every time I launch my PC it takes at least 10 minutes to login and launch application.

The problem started after I deleted two files called "gvfs" and "gvfs-admin". Now my PC has been lagging a lot!

```
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3050
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600th
8 GB of RAM
```

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy

Comment: The Search box at the top of the page is a great place to start it will tell you what information we need to offer useful advice and you can also see what other folks did to solve similar problems you didn't mention why you deleted important components of your system it would help ALOT!

Comment: Where were the files you deleted located?  Where did you get the advice to delete them?

Comment: Deleting anything especially files without knowing exactly what they do is never a good idea.